# Cross Domain Scripting (IE and Firefox only)

Tags: javascript, iframe, xmlhttprequest

Ive been asked to tackle a challenge where if we have JS delivered into an non-Friendly (aka Cross Domain) IFRAME (3rd party code being written to page), and from inside that IFRAME determine the x&y offset of the iframe into which the code is delivered. Due to cross site scripting limitations historically this has been deemed a non-starter, but we now have a need to have this ability. Anyone aware of any techniques that could get me started ?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by ditching the iframe, honestly. Cross-site scripting is one thing, but what you may be looking for is a web scraper.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Although I'm wondering if your intentions are benevolent if you're grabbing content from another site...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't ditch the IFRAME, and im not looking to execute or change the page content (nor do any malicious activity).   The purpose is to understand where on the page the IFRAME is written, basically trying to determine if the code we are serving onto the page within the IFRAME is in the user's viewport.